# MATLAB: Pass GUI parameters to script

Tags: matlab

I am running a script from a gui and I want to enter the value of some parameters called L_Al and L_InAs and pass these to the script. The following is a snippet of my GUI.m file, where I am running the script SchrodingerPoisson42 on pressing a button and trying to assign values to the parameters L_Al and L_InAs (see the last few lines):

```
    function L_InAs_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to L_InAs (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of L_InAs as text
    %        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of L_InAs as a double


    % --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
   function L_InAs_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to L_InAs (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

    % Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
    %       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
     if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
   end

    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    L_Al = str2num(get(handles.L_Al,'String'));
    L_InAs = str2num(get(handles.L_InAs,'String'));
    schrodingerpoisson42;
```

Comment: `assignin('base', 'L_Al', L_Al)` Look at the [`assignin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function documentation. A better idea would be to make your script a function `schrodingerpoisson42(L_Al,L_InAs)` which could take the parameters in input and not transport variables cross workspaces.

Comment: or declare those parameters as globals and change them from within your callback function when it gets called.

Comment: Or, better yet, those values into new properties of your gui figure handle, and update the values there when you press the button. Then in your main script, excplicitly assign to your variables the values via those figure_handle properties. This way, it is clear at all times what your variables are doing and what values they hold.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried assignin('base', 'L_Al', str2double(get(handles.L_Al,'String'))); How can I call the value of L_Al set by the GUI?

Comment: What do you mean "_How can I call ..._". After the call to `assignin` the variable should exist in the base workspace. If your script is calling this variable it it will find it.