# Plot in MATLAB gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to plot a set of variables taken from an external .m file in my MATLAB gui. Right now my piece of code looks like this:

```
    schrodingerpoisson42;
    axes(handles.axes1);
    plot(x1,V1);
```

The .m file is schrodingerpoisson42 and x1 and V1 are the variables from this script that I want to plot. For some reason it causes MATLAB to crash. What could be the problem? I have plotted other variables from schrodingerpoisson42 without any problems.

Edit: I can get the plot to work if I exclude the axes(handles.axes1) but then the plot opens a figure in a new window rather than plotting in the figure window defined by the GUI.

Edit2:

```
   % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
   function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
   % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
   % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
   axes(handles.axes1) 
   global L_Al 
   L_Al = str2double(get(handles.L1,'String'))*10^(-9);
   global L_InAs
   L_InAs = str2double(get(handles.L2,'String'))*10^(-9);
   schrodingerpoisson42;
   plot(x,V)
```

Comment: I assume `handles.axes1` is the handle to the axes you want to plot in? If so, try `plot(handles.axes1,x1,V1)`. And how bad is the crash: does your MATLAB process simply stop and quit to desktop? Does MATLAB or your OS generate an error?

Comment: yes that was the idea. But maybe MATLAB fails to recognize the handle or something. The suggestion you made returned "invalid handle". How can I make MATLAB recognize the handle axes1. Do I need to define it somewhere? After I created it in guide it does not show up anywhere in the GUI code.

Comment: I have no experience with writing MATLAB GUIs. It sounds like the `handles.axes1` axes handle isn't created properly. Are you building a MATLAB app or a GUI using GUIDE?

Comment: Are you executing this code snippet in your GUI code or in the command window? More information is needed to define your issue, there isn't enough here for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "MATLAB crashes"? You mean there is an error? Or does the program literally segfault?

Comment: the code snippet is inside the callback function in the GUI file. When I include the line axes(handles.axes1) it causes MATLAB to give an error message saying I should end it now. I think I may have solved this now. But still the plot function opens a new window rather than plotting in the GUI window. What could cause this? I have included more code in the OP now.

Comment: I have seen this code somewhere ... ho yes, there it is: [Pass GUI parameters to script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703251/matlab-pass-gui-parameters-to-script) ... but why the different user name ? Anyway, `x` and `V` are not declared `global` in your callback, how can the function know their value ?